# Transform column values into individual columns in R

Tags: r, text, dataframe

The data frame is somewhat like this

```
 X                       Y
1 Fruit            Apple, Banana, Orange
2 Vegetable        Cauliflower, Potato, Brinjal
3 Cuisine          Thai, Indian, Japanese
4 Fruit            Grape, Watermelon, Papaya
5 Vegetable        Pumkin, Cabbage, Broccoli
6 Cuisine          Mexican, English, Chinese
```

And I want it to transform into something like this

```
 Fruit                        Vegetable                           Cuisine
1 Apple, Banana, Orange      Cauliflower, Potato, Brinjal    Thai, Indian, Japanese
2 Grape, Watermelon, Papaya  Pumkin, Cabbage, Broccoli       Mexican, English, Chinese
```

Any hints gratefully received.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you @Cath :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a sequence column and then use `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Seq := seq_len(.N), X]
dcast(df1, Seq~X, value.var="Y")[, Seq := NULL][]
#                       Cuisine                     Fruit                    Vegetable
#1:    Thai, Indian, Japanese     Apple, Banana, Orange Cauliflower, Potato, Brinjal
#2: Mexican, English, Chinese Grape, Watermelon, Papaya    Pumkin, Cabbage, Broccoli
```

---

If we use the devel version of `data.table`, this is more direct and more efficient

```
dcast(setDT(df1), rowid(X)~ X, value.var="Y")
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
data.frame(split(df1$Y, df1$X))
#                       Cuisine                     Fruit
#1    Thai, Indian, Japanese     Apple, Banana, Orange
#2 Mexican, English, Chinese Grape, Watermelon, Papaya
#                     Vegetable
#1 Cauliflower, Potato, Brinjal
#2    Pumkin, Cabbage, Broccoli
```

Comment: How do we tackle, let's say, X values are not uniform sequence? For example here - from row 1 - 6 is Fruit, Vegetable, Cuisine, Fruit, Vegetable, Cuisine. What if we miss Cuisine in between in the sequence?

Comment: @Loy The `dcast` method will provide missing values `NA` to fill up those elements that are not there.

Comment: Okay. Let me check. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

This will give you a list instead of a data frame if the number of items in each category is not the same,

```
unstack(df, Y ~ x)
#                    Cuisine                     Fruit                    Vegetable
#1    Thai, Indian, Japanese     Apple, Banana, Orange Cauliflower, Potato, Brinjal
#2 Mexican, English, Chinese Grape, Watermelon, Papaya    Pumkin, Cabbage, Broccoli
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. This was because I did not use the whole table provided by OP and there was a different number of items which coerced the output to list